# FBRequest get photos of album

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the cover photo of a specific album from a page in Facebook.

```
for(NSDictionary *album in albums)
         {
             [albumNames addObject:[album objectForKey:@"name"]];
             NSLog(@"%@\n", [album objectForKey:@"id"]);
             [[FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos", [album objectForKey:@"id"]] parameters:nil HTTPMethod:nil]
              startWithCompletionHandler:
              ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                FBGraphObject *albumPhoto,
                NSError *error) {
                  if(!error) {
                      [albumCoverPhotos addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[albumPhoto objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"picture"]]]]];
                  }
              }];
         }
```

But it never executes the line `if(!error)` so `albumCoverPhotos` is empty at the end of this code.

My objective is to put all the cover images of all the album of the page in the array `albumCoverPhotos`.

Comment: So, it could be an error here. Put after NSLog(error.localizedDescription); and see what it tells

Comment: The error is 200, it works, I misread the structure of the album in graph API explorer :)